# Hive query for exploding list of values in a json

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

**Json**

```
{
"Event": "StudentMarks",
"Marks Info": {
    "Marks": [{
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Sub1",
        "Value": "95"
    }, {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "Sub2",
        "Value": "96"
    }, {
        "ID": 3,
        "Name": "Sub3",
        "Value": 100
    }]
  },
"Grade": {
    "metric": "pass"
    }
}
```

Im trying to get the Value under **Marks Info** json which has list of jsons with key **Marks**. Im able to get the values but Im unable to split that out like separate value.

**Query Im using**

```
 select  Student_ID, get_json_object(get_json_object(json_blob,'$.Marks Info'), '$.Marks[*].Value') from my_table where my_condition;
         
  Student_ID    |get_json_object(get_json_object(json_blob, '$.Marks Info'), '$.Marks[*].Value')
       1        |                  ["95","96,100"]
```

**Required Output**

I want the columns names should be Sub1 Sub2 Sub2 Grade like this and values should explode from the list  **["95","96,100"]**

Would anyone help me with this query?

```
     Student_ID | Sub1  | Sub2|    Sub2 |    Grade    
        1       | "95"  | "96"|    100  |   "pass"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. get_json_object returns a string, so you need to fiddle with it to get what you want.

```
select
    Student_ID,
    trim('[]"', x[0]) sub1,
    trim('[]"', x[1]) sub2,
    trim('[]"', x[2]) sub3,
    grade
from (
    select
        Student_ID,
        split(get_json_object(json_blob, '$.Marks Info.Marks[*].Value'), ',') x,
        get_json_object(json_blob, '$.Grade.metric') grade
    from my_table
)
```